# Ms Computer Vision API image url replace as local .jpg using Python

Tags: python, azure, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to write a python program on Pi to capture an image and get the description from Ms Computer Vision API. It is working with using image_url as *"http://website.com/abc.jpg"*, but when I change to my local image *"abc.jpg"*, it is have an error.

> File "ms.py", line 71, in 
>       response.raise_for_status()
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.19.1-py2.7.egg\requests\models.py", line 939, in raise_for_status
>       raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
>   requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/analyze?visualFeatures=Categories%2CDescription%2CColor

The original working code is below:

```
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import simplejson as json
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

subscription_key = "XXXX"
assert subscription_key

vision_base_url = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/"

analyze_url = vision_base_url + "analyze"

# Set image_url to the URL of an image that you want to analyze.
image_url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/12/" + \
"Broadway_and_Times_Square_by_night.jpg/450px-Broadway_and_Times_Square_by_night.jpg"

headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key }
params  = {'visualFeatures': 'Categories,Description,Color'}
data    = {'url': image_url}
response = requests.post(analyze_url, headers=headers, params=params, json=data)
response.raise_for_status()

# The 'analysis' object contains various fields that describe the image. The most
# relevant caption for the image is obtained from the 'description' property.
analysis = response.json()
print(json.dumps(response.json()))
image_caption = analysis["description"]["captions"][0]["text"].capitalize()

# Display the image and overlay it with the caption.
image = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(image_url).content))
plt.imshow(image)
plt.axis("off")
_ = plt.title(image_caption, size="x-large", y=-0.1)
plt.show()
```

so when replacing image_url as "abc.jpg" or "C:/abc.jpg", it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you should read image before send like this :

```
# Set image_path to the local path of an image that you want to analyze.
image_path = "C:/Documents/ImageToAnalyze.jpg"

# Read the image into a byte array
image_data = open(image_path, "rb").read()

response = requests.post(
    analyze_url, headers=headers, params=params, data=image_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But there is an error. "**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte**" at the line - `response = requests.post(analyze_url, headers=headers, params=params, json=image_data)`

if I use `data=image_data`, then the error is     **requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://westcent...**

Comment: Use data=image_ data with this headers and tell me :
headers    = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
              'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}

Comment: Thank you so much, it works with adding `, 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'` .

Answer (score 0):

###### Set image_path to the local path of an image that you want to analyze.

image_path = "Image location (local path)"

###### Read the image into a byte array

image_data = open(image_path, "rb").read()

headers    = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}

params     = {'visualFeatures': 'Categories,Description,Color'}

response = requests.post(
ocr_url, headers=headers, params=params, data=image_data)

response.raise_for_status()

###### The 'analysis' object contains various fields that describe the image. The most relevant caption for the image is obtained from the 'description' property.

analysis = response.json()

print(analysis)